# Problem Installing Git

Tags: apt, software-installation, git

I am using Xubuntu on a virtual machine and my internet is working fine. I'm trying to install git and `sudo apt-get install git` is also not working.

Terminal says:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives
Maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

im not sure but try `sudo apt-get install git --fix-missing` or you can build it from the source with this guide [Check Build Git from source on Linux
 section](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#linux)